# A phrase highlighting the use of articles

Tags: articles

Is there a canonical phrase or short text that illustrates all possible uses of articles ('a', 'the', no article) in English? Many thanks.

Comment: No. It would have to be several pages long because there are a hundred or more mostly idiomatic uses of articles in English, and no canon to deal with them.

Comment: No and if there was, don't you think you'd find more suitable help at SE English Language Learners or SE Writing?